# Is it possible to package an .exe application in a war file?

Tags: file, exe, war

I have one web application(.war) file. There is one tool (.exe) which is used for some computation but it is currently outside of this web application. We have a requirement, where we need to package this .exe file and .war file into single .war file, so that user can just click a particular link and .exe will be opened from the .war file.

My question is, is it possible to package both (exe and war) into the single war file?  If yes, can please let me know the convinient way. I did some googling but most of the answer shows converting war to an exe file, which i dont require.

Answer (score 0):

A war file is nothing more than a zip archive, as such you can place whatever you want inside.

Now the use case seems strange. Do you intend to download the executable from the website?

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for the reply. This tool(exe) does some calculation, and the user wants that when he is browing through the web application, he should be able to open the tool, do some calculation and based on some value fill the form in the web application and then proceed. For your question, No i dont want to download any executable from the website.